# Javascript not populate chart after retrieve json data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, chart.js

I have a `div` to handle chart `<div id="LineSumbalance"></div>` and `textbox` to key parameter, `button` to fire.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchTerm" runat="server" Width="200px" class="form-control" placeholder="Terminal Number" spellcheck="false"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSearchTerm" runat="server" Text="Search" class="btn  btn-primary" />
```

I write a code behind to query data from database:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function GetChart(ByVal Tdate As String, ByVal Term As String) As List(Of Object)
    Dim BizFunc As New BizFunction.UtilFormat
    Dim chartData As New List(Of Object)()

    Dim TabName As String = "TA" & Tdate
    Dim TodayDate As String = BizFunc.Date2YYMM(Today.Date)
    Dim labels As New List(Of String)()
    If Tdate = Mid(TodayDate, 1, 4) Then
        TabName = "(select * from " & TabName & " union all select * from TA" & TodayDate & ") TA "
    End If
    Dim query As String = "WITH t1  AS (SELECT dt,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,'1900-01-01',dt),'1900-01-01') AS firstInMonth,DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,'1900-01-01',dt)+1,'1900-01-01')) AS lastInMonth,amount " &
        " FROM(SELECT CONVERT(DATE, tran_date) AS dt,COUNT(*) AS AMOUNT FROM " & TabName & " WHERE TERM Like '%" & Term.PadRight(16, " ") & "%' and (TRANS = '05' or TRANS = '06') GROUP BY TRAN_DATE) AS st " &
        "Group BY dt, amount), " &
        "Calendar  " &
        " AS (SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(DAY, c.number,t1.firstInMonth) AS d FROM t1 JOIN master..spt_values AS c On type = 'P' AND DATEADD(DAY,c.number,t1.firstInMonth) BETWEEN t1.firstInMonth AND t1.lastInMonth) " &
        " Select DatePart(dd, d) Date, Case When amount Is NULL Then 0 Else amount End As amount FROM calendar As c LEFT JOIN t1 On t1.dt = c.d;"
    Dim dtbal As DataTable = GetData(query)

    Dim series1 As New List(Of Integer)()

    For Each row As DataRow In dtbal.Rows
        labels.Add(Convert.ToString(row("Date")))
    Next
    chartData.Add(labels)
    For Each row As DataRow In dtbal.Rows
        series1.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row("AMOUNT")))

    Next
    chartData.Add(series1)
    Return chartData
End Function
```

Above code are working perfectly.

The problem is on `Javascript`:

```
$(function () {
$("[id*=btnSearchTerm]").click(function () {
        LoadChart();
    });
});
function LoadChart() {
    var tdate = $("[id*=txtdate]").val();
    var term = $("[id*=txtSearchTerm]").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MonthlyBalancing.aspx/GetChart",
        data: "{TDate: '" + tdate + "', term: '" + term + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            var labels = r.d[0];
            var series1 = r.d[1];
                var data = {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "Dataset1",
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.31)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                        pointBorderColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                        pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointBorderWidth: 1,
                        data: series1
                    }]
            };

                $("#LineSumbalance").html("");
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            $("#LineSumbalance")[0].appendChild(canvas);

            //Fix for IE 8
            if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == "8.0") {
                G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
            }
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    var lineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
                bezierCurve: false
                    });

        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert('There was an error.');
        }
    });
}
```

I try to alert on every row and it's stuck on `$.Ajax`. It's not execute anything even failure.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one issue with naming: your control is `<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate"` but you call `$("[id*=txtdate]").val();` which seems need to be `txtDate` (with capital D) too.

Regarding ajax - you need to debug the function to ensure what it gets on every step. Add `debugger;` or `alert();` where it is necessary and run the code. For example, add

```
...
success: function (r) {
   alert(r);
   var labels = r.d[0];
...
```

and see if `r` will be defined.